# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I get the following error when I try to run the app (see below). Already tried the solutions posted on similar topics.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
    at com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.OffersDAO.getOffers(OffersDAO.java:26)
    at com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.App.main(App.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

After reading the solution from other similar topics I've tried the below:

```
- GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
- Change jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb to jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb
- Create a new User
```

If I go from my CMD and I try `C:\mysql-5.6.21-winx64\bin>mysql -u root -p -h localhost` I can log in with no probs.

Any other suggestions please before I will uninstall Mysql and try to reinstal.

Comment: can post `context.xml` if you use tomcat

Answer (score 3):

The error `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` , mysql login failed using the provided credentials.

two things you can check.

1. If the provided password is a valid one.
2. Grant privileges.

It should be like ,

```
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '[user name]'@'[server machine name]' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]' WITH GRANT OPTION;'

 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you didn't execute flush privileges you are likely to get the same error.

eg:

```
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_mysql_password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```